# Creating Facebook Page programmatically through Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am hoping there is a way to create a facebook page using the open graph API. The documentation only shows API calls I can make once the page exists.

Currently, I have movie profiles on my site that I would like to create a page for each on Facebook.  I know I can just add the Like button and once clicked, it will create the page for me.  But I'm hoping to have a programmatic way to do the same.

Comment: Facebook bug about this: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10714

Comment: That URL is no longer accessible. I've filed a new bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/455171321210906 .

Comment: Forgot to put @thaddeusmt on that previous comment. D'oh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this thread, there's no way to create pages programmatically

[Link to the thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=89270)

Comment: So this Open Graph API method mentioned in the Developer info just worked on pages that have already been Liked? The "/OBJECT_ID/likes" "write" action that "Like the given object (if it has a /likes connection)"? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 4):

You can do this programatically but it's kind of a hack. If you include the Facebook Comments plugin it will autocreate the page for you. So if you make a general webpage that takes parameters like movieID, you can make a script that does a HTTP GET for every ID that you have available and all the graph objects will be created.

Like this:

```
<fb:comments href="www.mypage.com?id=<%=request.getParameter("movieid")%>" num_posts="35" width="340" colorscheme="light"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate bit more on this? I think you are on to something here..., If Facebook has not already picked up on it....

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs you can curl the url linter with your url. However, this is *very* slow. C.f. the [following link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

The technique mentioned in another post on this page (of GETting a page with a Comments Plugin on it) probably wont work unless your getter is actually a browser than will run javascript :-)  I have tried this with a Like button on a page I want scraped, and no dice, an admin on that page actually has to click Like for it to get scraped.

Comment: How does this relates to page creation on Facebook ? Any examples you have ?