# automatic facebook page creation

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Facebook Page programmatically through Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926113/creating-facebook-page-programmatically-through-open-graph-api)

Good Day!

I would like to ask if the automatic facebook page creation using api is possible? I want to create a facebook page and I like to create it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible. There would be a lot of spam

Answer (score 0):

I doubt they would allow this. It would allow too much spam.