# creating of facebook fan pagere any

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Facebook Page programmatically through Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926113/creating-facebook-page-programmatically-through-open-graph-api)

I'm trying to create a fan page from remote.
Is there any way to create through PHP/JS SDK a new fan page?
(I'm not talking about posting but creating)

Answer (score 0):

No, Facebook has no API for creating pages. It's supposed to be something you rarely do and put some thought into.