# I need to create facebook page using API or PHP Curl or facebook restserver?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Facebook Page programmatically through Open Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926113/creating-facebook-page-programmatically-through-open-graph-api)

How can i do it?

if it's not possible, which is the more easy way to create a page?

I'm doing a web system and i need to make it easy to the user.

Maybe i could do something using access token?? I found this http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4926113/creating-facebook-page-programmatically-through-open-graph-api, but i don't understand it...

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't understand it then please explain what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for creating a page. At the bottom of every facebook page is this link:

[Create a Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?ref_type=sitefooter)

Which you can use to create a page.

Comment: not have a way to do it using restserver facebook?, i got access token of the user.

Comment: As far as I know, pages must be created manually by the user. No way to automate it.

Comment: sorry for the dupe response.  Didn't see it until the page refreshed.  Removing my dupe.

Comment: @user1207879 no there is no authorize way to create page automatically because maybe facebook wants to allow pages for Product, Brands etc but maybe not want lots of pages of one name or for one business :)