# How to create a Facebook fan page for a website in an automated way?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, automation, facebook-page

We are working on a CMS application development. In that case, we need to integrate a feature, that is enabled for user to create a facebook fan page in an automated way for their product/service. But we realized that it's not allowed by any of facebook developer APIs.

So, What we just need is to automation of fan page creation part in a programmatic way. Is that possible to do??

Thanks!

Comment: I say no facebook not allow to create any pages programmatic way...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Facebook Page programmatically through Open Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926113/creating-facebook-page-programmatically-through-open-graph-api)

Comment: That's currently impossible unfortunately.

Comment: @BjörnKaiser they appear to be asking two different questions, although the difference isn't obvious. The question you linked wants to generate Open Graph objects for each page on their site. That question should probably be edited to reflect this.

This question is asking if it's possible to programmatically generate a true Facebook Page (aka facebook.com/someUserName) for a product. This is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a new Facebook Page via the API - for example, if your client had a company called SomeCompany, they could not use your app to generate a Product/Service Page at www.facebook.com/SomeCompany for users to Like. Your alternatives are:

1) Use your app to generate Open Graph tags and Like buttons for the company's web site (external to Facebook).
2) Instruct the client on how to create a page manually by visiting Facebook.com while logged into their Facebook account.
3) Request the manage_pages permission from your client in your app, and use the Marketing API to edit the page after the client has created it. You can edit most fields on the page (even things like the profile picture) once the page exists. For more information, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/